# custom resources in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm new to chef and ruby programming. I'm sure custom resources is a kind function to prevent repetition of work in the code.  How should I use custom resources in a recipe that has key value pair property for various resources?

Comment: example: 

resource 1 
cassandra_user = node['dbaas']['cassandra']['user']
cassandra_uid = node['dbaas']['cassandra']['uid']

resource 2
docker_image_name = attributes['docker']['image']['name']
docker_image_version = attributes['docker']['image']['version']

Comment: There are many recipes as such

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We don't allow these kinds of entirely open-ended questions here. You are better off using the discourse.chef.io mailing list or one of the Chef chat channels for introductory questions like this. If you have specific technical questions, please do ask them here in the future.

Comment: Have developed a custom resource with properties and actions in it. Kindly guide me on how to make the variables in it to get the correct value when used in different recipes that has the same properties with a small variation in the prefix as mongo_user, cassandra_user and elasticsearch_user. every recipe has its attributes as well.should i be using string replace or sub or any magical fucntion ?

Comment: Like I said, we don't allow questions like that on StackOverflow. The Chef docs would be the place to go for open-ended "how do I do this?" questions.